# ArcGIS REST service is returning error when distinct param is supplied

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

ArcGIS REST service (10.4.1) is returning the error

```
Unable to complete operation.
Unable to perform query operation.
```

When `ReturnDistinct=true` and `InputGeometry` is supplied.
This operation works correctly if `ReturnDistinct=false`

Full query params as below

```
query?where=
&objectIds=
&time=
&geometry=%7B"xmin"%3A16712664.599773334%2C"ymin"%3A-2674043.1889597364%2C"xmax"%3A16772285.481835691%2C"ymax"%3A-2639761.1817738814%2C"spatialReference"%3A%7B"wkid"%3A102100%7D%2C"cache"%3A%7B"_parts"%3A%5B%7B"extent"%3A%7B"xmin"%3A16712664.599773334%2C"ymin"%3A-2674043.1889597364%2C"xmax"%3A16772285.481835691%2C"ymax"%3A-2639761.1817738814%2C"spatialReference"%3A%7B"wkid"%3A102100%7D%7D%2C"frameIds"%3A%5B0%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D
&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope
&inSR=
&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects
&distance=
&units=esriSRUnit_Foot
&relationParam=
&outFields=
&returnGeometry=false
&maxAllowableOffset=
&geometryPrecision=
&outSR=
&gdbVersion=
&returnDistinctValues=true
&returnIdsOnly=false
&returnCountOnly=false
&returnExtentOnly=false
&orderByFields=
&groupByFieldsForStatistics=
&outStatistics=
&returnZ=false
&returnM=false
&multipatchOption=
&resultOffset=
&resultRecordCount=
&f=html
```

Comment: are you looking at an ArcGIS rest endpoint version before 10.1?

Comment: 10.4.1, good point added to question.